# Convert String to xpath in XSLT

Tags: xslt

I find difficulty in converting string to xpath in xslt

**XSLT**

```
 <xsl:param name="name"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:if test="$name">
      <xsl:message><xsl:value-of select="$name"/></xsl:message>
      <xsl:value-of select="$name"/>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
```

param 'name' value (Xpath expression) will  be passed from java. What should i do in xsl to consider this string as xpath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're asking for is something akin to the `eval` function of languages such as Perl, to treat a string as an expression in the language.  This is not something that XSLT 1.0 or 2.0 provides natively, though many processors provide support through extension functions such as [EXSLT](http://www.exslt.org/dyn/functions/evaluate/index.html).  The current XSLT 3.0 working draft provides a similar mechanism, which is [supported by Saxon](http://saxonica.com/documentation/xsl-elements/evaluate.xml).